# Erro de sessão Amadeus com cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

Primeiramente, venho esclarecer de que sei que a documentação é privada.
Eu tenho a documentação em mãos, segui tudo direito, mas o amadeus segue dando este erro:

> 17|Session|No agreement on destination

Meu método no Client.php está asism:

```
public function pnrCancel($pnr_id){
    //die($pnr_id);
    $params = array();        
    $params['PNR_Cancel']['pnrActions']['optionCode'] = 10;        
    $params['PNR_Cancel']['cancelElements']['entryType'] = 'I';  
    $params['PNR_Cancel']['reservationInfo']['reservation'] = $pnr_id; 


    $this->_data = $this->_client->__soapCall('PNR_Cancel', $params, null,
        $this->getHeaderSession(), $this->_headers);  

    $this->debugDump($params, $this->_data);
}
```

E a minha action está assim:

```
public function deletePnr($pnr){        
     $ws = new Client(__DIR__ . DS . '..' . DS . 'wsdl' . DS . '1ASIWIOPIEM_PDT_20140828_132845.wsdl', false);
        $ws->securityAuthenticate('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx=', lenght, 'xxx');
        $ws->pnrCancel($pnr);
        $pnrXml = $ws->getXml();
        $ws->securitySignout();                                                                           
}
```

Já fiz de tudo, mas insiste em dar esse erro de session, todas minhas outras funções de pnr funcionam normalmente.

Answer (score -2):

Não esqueça de enviar o SOAPAction="htts://websevices.amadeus.com/{1ASIWIOPIEM}/{serviceVersion}" no header do serviço.
Este erro informa que você não tem permissão de acesso ao serviço.
Valide o SOAPAction  enviado no serviço Security_Authentication.